# console:doctrine:import with filter return an error on another table

Tags: symfony, import, doctrine, entity, symfony4

Hello i try to import  an existing SQL table on symfony by converting it in Entity.
I'm using the command :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity --filter=myfilter -em=myem
```

i get the following error on a another table in the database.
Table x has no primary key. Doctrine does not support reverse engineering from 
tables that don't have primary key.

How can i make my command work according to the fact that i don't want Symfony to handle this entity x that's why i'm using filter

Comment: What are you writing in the `--filter` option? As I remember, it is used like `--filter="table_name"`. Also you have mistake near `-em` there must be double `-` - `--em=default`

Comment: yes the filter contain my table name and effectively i made a mistake in writing the command here but i'm using --em=myem. i think the filter is working but doctrine seem to have to explore all the sql application even for importing a specific table from it. there is not way to force doctirne to work without exploring all the other table not concerned by the filter action?